# List relationships in pig

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a list like this:

```
a, 2
b, 1
a, 5
c, 5
d, 3
a, 3
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
a,  2,3,5
b,  1
c,  5
d,  3
```

In other words, I need to find the numbers that are related to a letter.

What I'm thinking is that I can filter and get a list of unique letters (a,b,c,d) and then for each one, I would need to find the numbers that are related.

How can I find all the number that are related? Do I need to do it one by one? if I have a very large data set, would it wokr? or is there some facility in pig that I can use to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input:**

```
a, 2
b, 1
a, 5
c, 5
d, 3
a, 3
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (col1:chararray,col2:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY col1;
C = FOREACH B {
                 sortedRow = ORDER A BY col2 ASC;
                 GENERATE group,FLATTEN(REPLACE(BagToString(sortedRow.$1.col2),'_\\s+',','));
              }
STORE C INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

**Output:** (will be stored in `output/part*` file)

```
a, 2,3,5
b, 1
c, 5
d, 3
```